# How to create custom adminhtml theme magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I try to extends default adminhtml magento theme.

So I create a file in: **app/design/adminhtml/default/myTheme**

And also create a new module, I know that my module load because it appear in the modules lists in **System->Configuration->Advanced** and in my `config.xml` (of this module), I write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <package>
                    <name>default</name>
                </package>
                <theme>
                    <default>myTheme</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

But when I run this:

```
<?php var_dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());?>
```

I get this:

> array(7) {...[2]=> string(31) "THEME_adminhtml_default_default"...}
>
> And I expected for:
>
> array(7) {...[2]=> string(31) "THEME_adminhtml_default_**myTheme**"...}

Why the module don't loads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Foo_myTheme>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Foo_myTheme>
  </modules>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <package>
                    <name>default</name>
                </package>
                <theme>
                    <template>myTheme</template>
                    <skin>myTheme</skin>
                    <layout>myTheme</layout>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```